# C++ determine first character of var value

Tags: c++, comparison

I have a function that passes an ID using the `const char* idname`

I'm currently using `strcmp` to compare `idname` to a string.
eg:

```
    if(strcmp(idname, "localuser") == 0) {
        // then I know idname is localuser
     }
```

what I really like to do is the following:

```
if first character of idname is a number then foo =1

if first character of idname is an upper case letter then foo =2

if first character of idname is a lower case letter then foo =3
```

How do I test for this ?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `std::string`?

Comment: The [character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) might be helpful.

Comment: A simple `if`/ `else if` cascade using `std::is_digit(idname[0])` and `std::is_upper(idname[0])` should do.

Comment: Just want to add that all solutions suggested so far only work with ASCII strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are library functions for that:

```
char c = idname[0];
if (std::is_digit(c))
{
    foo = 1;
}
else if (std::is_upper(c))
{
    foo = 2;
}
else if (std::is_lower(c))
{
    foo = 3;
}
```

These work regardless of whether your platform uses ASCII or something else.

Comment: And AFAIK not only for non-ASCII, but they actually also work with higher ASCII characters, which are locale dependent (such as that `'Ü'` is an uppercase letter and `'ü'` an lowercase letter). But for that the locale needs to be set appropriately according to the string code page (which would normally be the default locale anyway).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should ensure that there is the first character.

```
if (!idname || !*idname) return;
```

Then you may compare your first character

```
char firstChar = idname[0];
```

against ranges.
Numbers are from '0' to '9', or 48 to 57.
Lower case english letters are from 'a' to 'z', or 97 to 122.
Upper case ones are from 'A' to 'Z', or 65 to 90.
This works for ASCII strings. Unicode may require more sophisticated algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* idname = 'a'; // or whatever

if (isalpha(idname )) {
   if ( (int) idname >= 65 && (int) idname <= 90) foo = 2;
   else if ( (int) idname >= 97 && (int) idname <= 122) foo = 3;

} else if (isdigit(c)) {
   foo = 1;
}
```

Something like that should work. Check it, I didn't test it. isalpha() and isdigit() are standard functions in .